# jQuery .addClass does not change css

Tags: jquery, addclass

Ideally I want to hover over my `<li>` in my menu and highlight each `<li>` but as a test I have the following to change the class on hover. Any thoughts why this won't work?

Thanks so much.

```
.dropdownhoverIn a:hover
{
    background-color: White;
    color: #39C;
}
```

---

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="multiDropMenu">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#" id="places">Places</a>
                    <ul id="dropdown1">
                        <li><a href="http://google.com">To Go</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">To See</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Transportation</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu li").hover(function() {
        $(this).find("ul").find("a").hover(function() {   
            $(this).addClass("dropdownhoverIn"); 
        });
        $(this).find("ul").slideToggle(250);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the "inner" `.hover()` assignment,

```
$("#menu > li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("ul a").addClass("dropdownhoverIn");
    $(this).find("ul").slideToggle(250);
});​
```

and the `:hover` pseudo selector on your class.

```
.dropdownhoverIn {
    background-color: White;
    color: #39C;
}​
```

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/GKZRU/

When you call `.hover()` a function parameter, you are *assigning* a handler. There's no reason to do that on each hover over the `<ul>`.

And if you're using jQuery's `.hover()`, you don't really need it in the CSS. If you want it there for compatibility, you need a separate CSS selector for it.

I also added `>` to the selector for the `.hover()` since I assume you want it to activate only on the child of `#menu`.

Comment: @Ehsan - What specifically do you mean when you say it's not working? I see the color of the text changing in my example. I don't know what your end result is supposed to look like.

Comment: Well unfortunately I mean exactly that, no color change nothing happens on my local machine. I'm running IE 7...no clue what's going on that is different in my environment.

Comment: @Ehasn - Does any of the jQuery work? And do the rest of your CSS rules work? I assume you can see it working in the jsFiddle example that I posted.

Comment: I think I know why now, does having another css class (lets call it LINKS) that deals with anchors override the class in "addClass" or does addClass simply add it to the existing class (ie. the LINKS class). OR does the new class in addClass override the LINKS class. Yep, it seems to work in the fiddle...Thanks for the help bud.